# BFF architecture with Python

Tags: python, django

I dont know if SO is the better place to discuss about that, but i need some opinions and suggestions about how to do a system using BFF architecture. I'm asking that, because at my internship i will need to refactor a system that was written with Golang and microsservices architecture with 4 services decoupled, and a BFF with Node. And now this system it will work with a single API and the BFF will be written in Python. Gimme some views about architecture and tools and how can i implement this. * I was thinking to implement that with Django, but i have never use this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello, did you evolve your ideas?

Comment: Do you see this: https://pypi.org/project/django-proxy-server/. ?

Comment: hello, my team use FastAPI with these kind of project, so i had no choices, haha, but i'm enjoying FastAPI, it's being nice developing this project with that framework... thanks for remember me that post and for your response.